# want to find maximum numbers from text file and want to assign the value for max number as 1 using java program

Tags: java

I have text files with some numbers like

```
   100
   38963
   27856
   0
   534
```

From this numbers i want to find maximum numbers and want to assign the value for max number as 1. From that i want to assign values to other numbers which is least.For example the first one want to give (38963/100)*100. I want to do all this using java program. Please anybody help me.

Comment: Please post your code/ideas you currently have.

Comment: Are you sure that you want (38963/100)*100 in your example, instead of 100/38963? I.e., are you trying to rescale your numbers to the interval [0,1]?

Answer (score 1):

To read lines of text from a file, you can wrap a [FileReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) in a [BufferedReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).  You can use [String.split()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split a line of text into tokens around spaces, and you can use [Integer.parseInt()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) to turn a `String` representing a valid integer into an `int`.

You can find the maximum and minimum of a list of `int`s in linear time (examining each int once) using two `int`s worth of storage.

That should be enough to get you started.

**Edit**: just realized those were supposed to be on separate lines (you should use the formatting tools when posting).  `String.split()` will be unnecessary, then.